# I need to host several websites on IIS 8 in Windows Server 2012 for public access

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I have a small server running Win 2012 and IIS and I have a public IP address from ISP. I bought several domain names for my websites. Usually I buy hosting service for hosting my website. Now I need to host on my server with domain that I have bought. I spend several days to find solution but cannot.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You'll first have to find out if your ISP allows incoming connections on port 80. Setup will be more difficult if they don't.

Comment: Your public IP address isn't dynamically assigned, is it?

Comment: My public ip is static from ISP. Do you have any tutorial for how to do this one? Actually I am web developer, it is difficult for me.

Comment: Does your ISP allow incoming connections on port 80? I'm assuming they do, but it would be good if you could confirm. If you don't know, you can confirm here: http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Comment: Yes, they don't allow.

Comment: I don't know how you would get around that unfortunately.